# $e^{x-1}$ has only one fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, chaos-theory

How does one show that the function $E(x)=e^{x-1}$ has only one fixed point? We know that there is only one integer solution for $e^{1-x} = x$, which is $x=1$, but *Wolfram Alpha* also gives a second answer in terms of some analytic function $W_n$, which I don't know.

How can it be proved that there is indeed one fixed point for $E(x)$?

We know that $E(x) \ge x$ for all $x$. One way is to prove that the equality holds only for $x=1$.

Comment: W is Lambert function i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$D(x) = E(x) -x = e^{x-1}-x$$ then you need to find all places where $D(x) = 0$. Note that $$D'(x) = e^{x-1}-1$$ and $$D''(x) = e^{x-1} > 0,$$ so $D$ is always concave up.

Moreover, $D'(x) > 0$ iff $x>1$, $D'(x) < 0$ for $x<1$. So $D(x)=0$ at $x=1$, and to the right one $1$, $D$ is increasing, and to the left - decreasing, so it never hits 0 again.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function $e^{x-1}-x$. You may differentiate it to show that prior to the zero at $x=1$, it is only decreasing, and after that zero, it is only increasing. Therefore $x=1$ must be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want points for which $e^{x-1} = x$.  If you plot those two functions ($y = e^{x-1}$ and $y = x$), you will see that they meet, at a tangent, at only one point: $(1, 1)$.